# Mootools - why not run?

Tags: mootools

you can test my code , when i click buton , we will get 2 link

click on first link , not alert

click on second link , show alert

why first link not alert, how to it can alert ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("mootools", "1.1.2");</script>
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $('button').addEvent('click', function(){
            $('content').innerHTML = $('test').innerHTML;
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="button" type="button" name="button" value="Click"/>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="test">
    <script>
        function test(){
            $('a-content').addEvent('click', function(){
                alert(1);
            });
        }
        window.addEvent('domready', function(){
            test();
        });
    </script>
    <a id="a-content" href="#">CLICK HERE</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: er. this is wrong. events are not delegated based upon id. if you have `el id="foo"` to which you attach an event and then you clone the element (via innerHTML) so you end up with ANOTHER element of the same id, the events attached won't work. it's wrong to have multiple elements with the same id anyway. why not have `<a class='a-content' href=''>` instead? even so, unless you do use event delegation (http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Delegation), cloning elements will mean you need to re-add the events as well. another bad thing - you clone innerHTML that contains a script tag...

Comment: also, if you addEvent to an id, then rewrite the element with the same id through parent innerHTML, the old event handler will stop to work as mootools uses a **per element** events system. each element is assigned a unique UID and events go under the mootools storage with the UID as key. removing and re-adding an element to the DOM with the same id= property means it will get a new UID and the old callbacks will no longer be referenced.

Comment: thank for suggetsion, i will try again

Answer (score 1):

When injecting HTML on the fly events aren't carried over unless you use event delegation. If you don't use event delegation the event will only be on the original element. See http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Delegation

You'll need to do something like this. $('body').addEvent('click:relay(#a-content)', function(){...}); Where the body would capture the click event and delegate it to any element with the id of "a-content".

Also by setting the content like this $('content').innerHTML = $('test').innerHTML; you will have duplicate elements with the id "a-content" this is wrong. HTML id's should be unique. Try classing stuff that you'll reuse instead.